# Three way sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have implemented a three-way sort algorith in Java. Say I the following array :

```
int myArray[] = {8,3,5,7,9,2,3,5,5,6}
```

I would need to become `2 3 3 5 5 5 6 7 8 9`, obviously. My algorithm is working except for the "2". In fact, I get the following output :

```
3 3 5 5 5 6 7 2 8 9
```

I have no clue why...

```
/* 
     * DESCRIPTION OF mergeThreeWay ALGORITHM
     * 
     * merges sorted subarrays A[start...firstThird], A[firstThird+1,secondThird], and A[secondThird+1,stop]
     * 
     * There are 3 possible cases when one merges :
     *  1) all 3 sub-arrays have elements left
     *  2) only 2 sub-arrays have elements left
     *  3) only 1 sub-arrays have elements
     *  
     * What action to take?
     *  For case 1) select the smallest element from the 3 sub-arrays and add it to the temporary array
     *           2) select the smallest element from the 2 sub-arrays and add it to the temporary array
     *           3) this sub-array is sorted - add all elements to the temporary array
     * 
     * Finally, copy the temporary array to the original array
     * 
     * The algorithm uses while loops to iterate trough the sub-arrays until one sub-array has no elements left (all of its elements have been copied to the temp array)
     */
    public static void mergeThreeWay(int A[], int start, int firstThird, int secondThird, int stop) {
        int p1 = start;
        int p2 = firstThird;
        int p3 = secondThird;

        int tmp[] = new int[A.length];  // I need a temporary array of the same size as A because the sub-arrays keep their index, for example, a sub-array would look like this : [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
        int tmpIndex = start;

        // As long as tmpIndex as not reached the end of the array, execute the loop
        while(tmpIndex <= stop) {

            // Get the smallest elements of the three sub-arrays
            while (p1 < firstThird && p2 < secondThird && p3 <= stop) {
                if (A[p1] <= A[p2] && A[p1] <= A[p3]) {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p1++];
                }
                else if (A[p2] <= A[p1] && A[p2] <= A[p3]) {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p2++];
                }
                else if (A[p3] <= A[p1] && A[p3] <= A[p2]) {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p3++];
                } else {
                    tmpIndex++;
                }
            }

            // Get the smallest elements of the two remaining sub-arrays
            while (p1 < firstThird && p2 < secondThird) {
                if (A[p1] <= A[p2]){
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p1++];
                } else{
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p2++];
                }
            }

            while (p1 < firstThird && p3 < stop) {
                if (A[p1] <= A[p3]) {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p1++];
                } else {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p3++];
                }
            }

            while (p2 < secondThird && p3 < stop) {
                if (A[2] <= A[p3]) {    
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p2++];
                } else {
                    tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p3++];
                }
            }

            // Complete with the remaining elements

            while (p1 < firstThird) tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p1++];

            while (p2 < secondThird) tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p2++];

            while (p3 <= stop) tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p3++];

            tmpIndex++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
        for(int k=start; k <= stop; k++) {
            A[k] = tmp[k];
        }
    }
```

MAIN METHOD

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    int myArray[] = {8,3,5,7,9,2,3,5,5,6}; // an example array to be sorted. You'll need to test your code with many cases, to be sure it works.

    mergeSortThreeWay(myArray,0,myArray.length-1);

    System.out.println("Sorted array is:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i]+" ");
    }
    }
}
```

mergeSortThreeWay

```
 // sorts A[start...stop]s the same as the element at 
    public static void mergeSortThreeWay(int A[], int start, int stop) {

        if(start < stop) {

            // DIVIDE
            int firstThird = start + (stop - start) / 3;
            int secondThird = start + 2 * (stop - start) / 3;

            // CONQUER
            mergeSortThreeWay(A, start, firstThird);            // A[start..midLeft] SORTED
            mergeSortThreeWay(A, firstThird+1, secondThird);        // A[midLeft..midRight] SORTED
            mergeSortThreeWay(A, secondThird+1, stop);          // A[midRight..stop] SORTED

            // MERGER
            mergeThreeWay(A, start, firstThird, secondThird, stop);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample worked perfectly fine, see for Yourself: http://ideone.com/95AR6I

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int myArray[] = {8,3,5,7,9,2,3,5,5,6};
    mergeThreeWay(myArray,0,1,5,9);
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: if you call `mergeThreeWay(myArray, 0, 3, 6, 9);` it doesn't

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction. I thought my method was not working, but it was the way I was calling it! I changed to `int secondThird = start + 2 * (stop - start -1) / 3;` (notice the `-1`) in my `mergeSortThreeWay` and it now works. I have no idea why idea `-1` did the trick, but it's working :D

Comment: You should have "+1", not "-1". Imagine 9-element array [0-8] - to calulate firstThird (3) You need "start + (1/3 of 9)", e.g. "start + (stop-start+1)/3", then to invoke the recursion - You have to call it for [0-2] [3-5] and [6-8], current code invokes recursion for [0-3] [4-6] and [7-8] and then tries to apply the logic on [0-2] [3-5] [6-8] respectively (e.g. overlapping arrays)

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies within

```
while (p1 < firstThird && p2 < secondThird && p3 <= stop) {
        if (A[p1] <= A[p2] && A[p1] <= A[p3]) {
            tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p1++];
        }
        else if (A[p2] <= A[p1] && A[p2] <= A[p3]) {
            tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p2++];
        }
        else if (A[p3] <= A[p1] && A[p3] <= A[p2]) {
            tmp[tmpIndex++] = A[p3++];
        } else {
            tmpIndex++;
        }
    }
```

It will only work if the subgroups are sorted. you start by only comparing the starting elements of the sub groups and the smallest of those, and therefore not the whole subgroup. ie it will compare the values at `{A[start] A[firstThird] A[secondThird]}` only, which 2 isn't, and then put that first

The same problem is in the rest of your code, you aren't comparing against the smallest of the subgroups, our comparing against three values from each  of the subgroups which aren't the smallest.

**Edit:**

change to  `mergeThreeWay(A, start, firstThird+1, secondThird+1, stop);` and it will fix it. it is a simple fence post error. sice the first group you sort is from `start` to `firstThird`, when you merge you are accidently including the last element of the first group (at `firstThird`) in you r second group(when you set `p2= firstThird`.

also you need to fix `if (A[2] <= A[p3])` in `while (p2 < secondThird && p3 <= stop)`

would recommend either debugger or lots of `println`s in your code

Comment: hmm... and how would you fix that..?

Comment: You could try sorting the subgroups via recursion first.

Comment: Actually, if you check my mergeSortThreeWay method, I do recursion on subgroups